# Arnold's combinatorial description of entropy.

Tags: asymptotics, entropy, symmetric-polynomials

V.I. Arnold says that entropy is related to the asymptotic behaviour of polynomial coefficients. This is mentioned in his book "Dynamics, Statistics and Projective Geometry of Galois Fields".

Here is a snapshot of his words:

[image: Arnold's description of entropy]

[Reference: [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ohrcyhJKuGEC), Page 76.]

I want to know if someone here knows about this combinatorial description of entropy. An explanation or a reference will do.

Thanks!